# Set button value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="{loading : 'please wait...', !loading : 'start'}" />
```

However this does not work. I get the expression as value instead of please wait/start. Is there a built in angular directive to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking something like

```
<input type="submit" value="{{loading && 'please wait...' || 'start'}}" />
```

It works like ternary operator.

And if you are using Angular 1.1.5 or above this would work

```
<input type="submit" value="{{loading ? 'please wait...' : 'start'}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be old, but I thought I'd add this answer for `button` specific tag, since setting the value of button wasn't working for me.  I needed to add this as follows.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="actionAll();" 
             class="btn btn-default">{{loading ? 'please wait...' : 'start'}}</button>
```